# Java Serialization writeObject failing without defining variables

Tags: java, serialization, java-io

For some odd reason I am able to write my object to a file if broken up into variables or Strings but not as shown in the tutorial as one solid Object.

EXAMPLE SUCCESS:

```
public Book add(Book book){
        try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("stream.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        output.writeObject(book.getString1());
        output.writeObject(book.getString2());
        output.writeObject(book.getString3());
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("Falure to write!");
      }
        return book;
    }
```

While the following code completely bombs out and jumps to catch as soon as I attempt to write the Object:

EXAMPLE FAIL:

```
public Book add(Book book){
        try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("stream.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        output.writeObject(book);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("Falure to write!");
      }
        return book;
    }
```

Comment: And what's the stack trace of the exception? Exceptions have a type, and a message associated with them. Reading them gives good indications about the cause of the exception. Add e.printStackTrace() to your catch block to know the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Book` class should implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface

Also, what was the error message?

```
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: All of the fields in the `Book` class must be Serializable as well.

Comment: OH man I'm a dolt! Thank you very much! I will fix my catch statement as well so you can ignore that its just junk right now. Thanks bpgergo!

Comment: Just wondering, because I'm new to this, but if that was the correct answer, shouldn't you accept it?